# Privacy policy and TOS should open in own window

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you click to ask a company a question there are two links one for privacy policy and terms of service both should open in their _blank window but they don't.  When clicking either link you are navigating away from the page entirely.

Please change these links to `target="_blank"`

[image]

Comment: @Jason Punyon - This is still not working as expected, see my comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. Fixed now.

EDIT: Re-fixed now.

Comment: This is still not working correctly...Steps to reproduce...Do a job search, click to ask a question.  Click on the privacy policy / the other link..it opens overtop the main window.  Now close the dialog and click to open the dialog again, now click the links, now they open in a new window.  Perform another search, click to ask a question to the company, click privacy policy again...again it opens overtop the current site.  So some bug still exists.

Comment: @JonH: Try a hard refresh on the job details page (the one with the ask a question dialog)?

Comment: Trust me I did plenty of times.  You'll have to reproduce my steps, it works the first time, but go back to the search results.  Find a company, click to ask the company a question and click the link for privacy policy.  It completely overwrites it.

Comment: Ah. I see it now.

Comment: @JonH: Better now?

Comment: looks better (15 chars).